# JSON with irregular x axis highcharts Error 13

Tags: json, highcharts

For 10 hours, i'm trying to display data from a SQL database with highgraph. I've read some tutorials, so i can now produce a JSON file with my data like:

```
[{"name":"Temperature","data":[[1596642102000,-127],[1596642118000,-127],[1596642133000,-127]]},{"name":"Pres","data":[[1596642102000,214748364],[1596642118000,214748364],[1596642133000,214748364]]}]
```

But i can't put the data on highcharts

UPDATE:
I had to download the scripts, otherwise mozilla gave an error about mixed active contents

EDIT:
Here is my code: I've got the error 13 when i run it

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="../../code/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="../../code/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Basic line chart showing trends in a dataset. This chart includes the
        <code>series-label</code> module, which adds a label to each line for
        enhanced readability.
    </p>
</figure>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'test'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'test'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Snow depth (m)'
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        colors: ['#6CF', '#39F', '#06C', '#036', '#000'],


        series: [],
        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 500
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
    $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
        options.series[0] = json[0];
        options.series[1] = json[1];
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart('container',options);    
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Have you tried putting highcharts on top of all scripts? import highcharts script first and make Try.and there are multiple highcharts imports in your script.

Comment: I did this but i think the problem comes from this option thing because when i put the data in the right place i have the graph

Comment: Is the issue Resolved?

Comment: No, I try a lot of things but i can't manage to make this graph appear, I will start again with a demo from highcharts

Comment: series = [] replace with  series : [] you are using = in json?

Comment: I've done these things, I used console.log to see if the json was reight here
And now  I've got the error 13:

[Error 13](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/13/)

thank you for your help

Comment: I don’t fully understand This error, I’ve tried to add renderTo in chart options but it doesn’t work :(

Comment: Highcharts.chart('container', { ....option goes here});
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>

Comment: Thank you it works, i will update my first post so you can post the answer if you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create series data array with x and y values:

```
data: [ 
    // x, y
    [0, 1],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 8]
]
```

So convert your data to the format required by Highcharts or produce before a properly JSON structure.

```
options.series.forEach(function(s){
    s.data = s.data.map((el, i) => [json[0].data[i], el])
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u8f0hs5g/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answers but since yesterday i've already done this and now the error is the error 13 from Highcharts, i'm trying to resolve it

Comment: Hi @JulesL, Highcharts error #13 means that rendering div not found. Add `chart.renderTo` property: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.renderTo or add the container id as the first parameter in `Highcharts.chart` method: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.chart

Comment: yes thank you @Krishna Kanth has just give me the solution :)